# How to send form data in JSON format

Tags: javascript, extjs4, form-submit, rpc, ext-direct

I use ExtDirect to communicate server. I need to send form data in json to remote functions. It seems that it ignore `jsonSubmit` config and send data as form post. How should I config my API on the server and client that all file-free request be send in json format.

Comment: Would be helpful if you posted a sample of what you did and details of exactly what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Zend... Register provider class in Ext.Direct manager:

```
Ext.require(
    [
        'Ext.direct.*',
        'MyApp.lib.direct.ZendFrameworkProvider'
    ], function () {
        Ext.direct.Manager.addProvider(
            {
                'type': 'zf',
                'url': Ext.app.JSONRPC_API.target,
                'actions': Ext.app.JSONRPC_API.services,
                'format': 'json'
            });
    });
```

read more:

[Ext.Direct and JSON server based on Zend](http://devjs.eu/en/ext-direct-and-json-server-based-on-zend/)

and [Ext.Direct File Upload - Form submit of type application/json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25535784/ext-direct-file-upload-form-submit-of-type-application-json)